# Given $2$ integrating factors of $\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x,y)$ to find $f(x,y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question: Suppose $2$ integrating factors of $\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x,y)$ are $\mu_1 = \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$ and $\mu_2 = xy$. Find $f(x,y)$.

Suppose that $g(x,y)dx + h(x,y)dy = 0$, i.e. $f(x,y) = -\frac{g(x,y)}{h(x,y)}$. Then $$\frac{d}{dy}\frac{g(x,y)}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{h(x,y)}{x^2+y^2}$$

and

$$\frac{d}{dy}\{xyg(x,y)\} = \frac{d}{dx}\{xyh(x,y)\}.$$

However it seems not so easy to simplify. How to proceed to find $f(x,y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your calculus which is correct,
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{g}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{h}{x^2+y^2}\qquad (1)\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}xyg = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}xyh \qquad (2)
\end{cases}$$
From $(1)$ :
$$\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} -\frac{2y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}g
 = \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} -\frac{2x}{(x^2+y^2)^2}h
$$
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} =2\frac{xh-yg}{x^2+y^2} \tag 3
$$
From $(2)$ :
$$xy\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}+xg = xy\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}+yh $$
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} =\frac{xg-yh}{xy}\tag 4$$
From $(3)$ and $(4)$ :
$$2\frac{xh-yg}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{xg-yh}{xy}$$
$$2\frac{x-y\frac{g}{h}}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x\frac{g}{h}-y}{xy}$$
Since $\quad f=-\frac{g}{h}$ 
$$2\frac{x+yf}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{-xf-y}{xy}$$
Solving for $f\:$ leads to :
$$f(x,y) = -\frac{y\,(3x^2+y^2)}{x\,(x^2+3y^2)}$$

Comment: Thank you. However, the question is a little bit weird since the integrating factors of $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$, which is equivalent to $x(x^2+3y^2)dx+y(3x^2+y^2)dy=0$, should be $1$ and $xy(x^2+y^2)$.